# Apache NiFi on Windows machine failed to connect to MySQL database on same host

Tags: mysql, windows, jar, apache-nifi, mysql-connector

I have an instance of Apache NiFi running on the windows machine. I have failed to connect it with the MySQL database which is running on localhost and is accessible from any host.

I have attached the configurations of the connection

[image]

I tried to change the class name from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver and vice-versa without success, I also tried to change the Database connection URL port from 3306 t0 33061 and vice-versa also without any success.

on the bulletin board am getting the error "`No suitable driver for the given Database Connection URL: No suitable driver for the given Database Connection URL` and the status is stuck on enabling even after restarting the apache NiFi.

Please assist am stuck in here.

ps: I don't have password set for the root user of my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo in url - you have `jbds` instead of `jdbc`

Comment: I fixed it by changing the connection I had a typo in the Database Connection URL as you identified, I kind of missed it. Thanks